# JList selection to String and be able to save in a text file

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlist

I am Creating a program for my class that is a Pizza ordering Form. I have the code set so that whatever selection is chosen it is placed into a TextField called Getmetheorder. I would like put all the selections that were picked into a text file that would be the receipt of the order.

This is how I set up the list and this is working with out any issue.

```
Object selected[] = toplist.getSelectedValues();
        String tops = "";
        // Use a for loop to obtain the names of the selected items
        for (int k = 0;k < selected.length ; k++ )
        {
            tops += selected[k] + ",";
        }
        Getmetheorder.setText( sizepicked + tops );

String[] selectedItems = new String[selected.length];

for(int i=0; i<selected.length;i++){
selectedItems[i] = selected[i].toString();
```

I would like to make it so that when the user selects Pepperoni, peppers and mushrooms for example, insert that into this text file.

```
   try {
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("YourPizzaOrder.txt"));
out.write("Thank you for using the Online Pizza Ordering Program.");
out.newLine();
out.write("Your order was created on"+" "+today);
out.newLine();
out.write("*------------------------------------------------------*");
out.newLine();

out.write("a " + sizepicked + " With "+ //This is where i want the items from the Jlist to appear );
out.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  System.out.println("Exception ");
}
```

The sizepicked Variable is from a button group selection of small, medium, and large. That is working and outputting to the text file as planned. I am just a bit confused on how I would get the list selection to appear.

Comment: Do you want each item on a separate line or all on a single line?

Comment: All on 1 line would be great.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

this is for saving the selected items to a text file:

```
  List<Object> myList= list.getSelectedValuesList();
    try {
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("file.txt"),true));
        for(int i = 0 ; i<myList.size();i++){
            buffer.write(myList.get(i).toString());
            buffer.flush();
        }
        buffer.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //....
    }
```

and for showing all the selected values you can use `JTable` or `JList`, I would prefer `JList` it's easy for using :

```
JList list2 = new JList(myList.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
for (String value : selectedItems) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(value);
}

out.write("a " + sizepicked + " With "+ sb.toString());
```